# How do you give current page of website an other color in menubar?

Tags: html, css, menubar

I have a question concerning a menubar in html. I try to give the current page you're in an other color than the normal color in the menubar, but the code that I have written does not work.

```css
   #menubar,
    #menubar ul{
list-style: none;
margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#menubar>li{
float: left;
}

#menubar li a{
display: block;
height: 125%;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#menubar>li>a{
background-color: orangered;
color: #fff;
}
/*submenu*/
#Bloglijst{
position: absolute;
background-color: #efefef;
z-index: 9999;
display: none;
}

#Bloglijst>li>a{
color: #121;
width: auto;
}
#menubar li a:hover{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: chocolate;
 }
#menubar li:hover #Bloglijst{
display: block;
}


#ProjectLijst{
position: absolute;
background-color: #efefef;
z-index: 9999;
display: none;
}

#ProjectLijst>li>a{
color: #121;
width: auto;
}
#menubar li:hover #ProjectLijst{
display: block;
}
#welkomstekst{
margin-top: 10%;
}
#menubar{
width: 75%;
padding: 0;
}
.active{
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<li class="active"><a href="index.html"> Home </a> </li>
<li class="active" ><a href="HTML5/Blog.html"> Blog </a>
    <ul id= "Bloglijst">
        <li><a href="HTML5/Daily-Blog.html">Daily-Blog</a> </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="active"><a href="HTML5/Contact.html"> Contact </a>
<li class="active"><a href="HTML5/Projects.html"> Projects </a>
    <ul id= "ProjectLijst">
        <li><a href="HTML5/Sport.html">Sport</a> </li>
        <li><a href="HTML5/School.html">School</a> </li>
        <li><a href="HTML5/Hobby.html">Hobby</a> </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="active"><a href="HTML5/Interests.html"> Interests </a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="HTML5/Connections.html"> Connections </a></li>
```

Comment: you can apply an active tab http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200041/bootstrap-nav-tabs-dropdown-menus-how-to-set-active-tab-based-on-uri

Comment: check out my answer here to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514344/how-to-highlight-currently-opened-page-link-in-css/26514790#26514790

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397370/how-to-change-the-link-color-of-the-current-page-with-css

That answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of comments that link to suggestions, but just in case, here's the most simple way to handle what you want:

You have the class `.active` on each menu item, what you want is to have `.active` only on the menu item that corresponds with the current page. For example:

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.html"> Home </a> </li>
<li><a href="HTML5/Blog.html"> Blog </a>
...
```

This would be the markup for just your `index.html` page. Your `Blog.html` page would look something like this:

```
<li><a href="index.html"> Home </a> </li>
<li class="active"><a href="HTML5/Blog.html"> Blog </a>
...
```

Repeat this for each page and you should be setup correctly.

Then, simply apply the color you want to the `.active` class and it will only show on the current page.